# Google Play Services C++ / Run UI on second activity using IntentHandler

Tags: c++, android-intent, java-native-interface, google-play-services, cocos2d-x

I am developing a mobile game using Cocos2D-x engine for android platform and i want to integrate GPGS on it. 
I achieved to show leaderboards, but there is a little annoying problem. When leaderboard is visible, if i go background and then come back to app, the gamescene goes to black. I think opengl context being released and doesnt restore again. In my opinion running leaderboard on same activity causes this, the game engine cant understand whats happening there. Whatever, because of this  I want to run leaderboard (and also all GPGS things) on a new activity using intent.

> **Google likes "Providing"**
>   In the reference documents of Google Play Game Services C++ SDK, there is a few unclear/fuzzy explanation about using SetOptionalIntentHandlerForUI method.
>
> *"Provide a function that can start a provided UI intent at any point, using startActivityForResult."*
>
> **What is the mean of "Providing"?** What is a provided Intent? How will I use startActivityForResult method? Unfortunately, "using" and "providing methods" are not clear expressions for coding. There is no sample about
>   using this method in the documents of GPGS for C++. Eventually,
>    Google's document is so poor and
>   there is no useful information on the internet. If someone from Google helps me, I will be so happy.

As i understand, I wrote the code like this. But it gives error when starting.

AppActivity.java

```
public void runGPGSActivity(Intent i) {
    startActivityForResult(i,100);
}
```

AndroidPlatformConfiguration.h (From C++ gpg lib)

```
typedef std::function<void(jobject)> IntentHandler;

AndroidPlatformConfiguration &SetOptionalIntentHandlerForUI(
IntentHandler intent_handler);
```

main.cpp (JNI binding, the working code, GPGS runs on same activity )

```
gpg::AndroidPlatformConfiguration platform_configuration;
platform_configuration.SetActivity(activity);
StateManager::InitServices( ...
```

main.cpp (JNI binding, GPGS must be run on new activity )

```
gpg::AndroidPlatformConfiguration platform_configuration;

jclass activityClass = env->FindClass("org/cocos2dx/cpp/AppActivity");
jmethodID jIntentHandlerMethodID = env->GetMethodID(activityClass,"runGPGSActivity","(Landorid/content/Intent;)V");
jobject jIntentHandler = env->NewObject(activityClass, jIntentHandlerMethodID);

gpg::AndroidPlatformConfiguration::IntentHandler mIntentHandler; /*= [](jobject mjIntentHandler){};*/
std::function<void(jobject)> intentHandler = std::bind(mIntentHandler,jIntentHandler);

platform_configuration.SetOptionalIntentHandlerForUI(intentHandler);
platform_configuration.SetActivity(activity);

StateManager::InitServices(
```

There is no build error, but the application crashes when launching.

> 03-24 14:12:24.301: A/libc(21352): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at
>   0x00005368 (code=-6), thread 21352 (main)

And some links about this issue:

[IntentHandler reference](https://developers.google.com/games/services/cpp/api/classgpg_1_1AndroidPlatformConfiguration#member-typedef-documentation)

[StartActivityForResult reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int))

/// Thank you in advance. ///

Comment: Yep! Is there anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...Yeah I solved the problem, but didn't use IntentHandler method.

I was using this code in my app, to show weekly leaderboard data.

```
gameServices->Leaderboards().ShowUIBlocking(leaderboardId,gpg::LeaderboardTimeSpan::WEEKLY);
```

But return value is not void, it is UIStatus (whatever it is)

I've reverted back to this code, app is not going to black screen now. This method returns void, I think I have to catch some callbacks when using ShowUIBlocking method, with that UIStatus thing.

```
gameServices->Leaderboards().ShowUI(leaderboardId);
```

But now, I can't benefit from timespan feature of leaderboards.

I am going to research how it can be used. There is no problem for now. But, documentation of SetOptionalIntentHandlerForUI must be written more explicit, for programmers who want to use it.